# How to convert a space delimited file to a csv in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

My only use the first column of an csv.
For example, Col 1, row 1 has:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'C:/Users/~filename.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(url, sep= " ", header = None)
data.head()
```

Comment: Will you please show a sample of the actually CSV file? So `Identifier            First Name           Middle Name       Last Name       DOB` is actually just a single column value?

Comment: Yes exactly. I can show you a made up one because it has sensitive info. I will add it.

Comment: Is there a specific number of spaces that separates the different cells? Or is it different for some? Or are the tabs, not spaces? If so, how many?

Comment: 8 spaces, 9 words, They look like tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Since your column headers have space inside their name, you can't use `sep=" "` or `sep=\s+`. They will give the wrong split.

Instead, modify your split pattern to `sep=\s{2,}`:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(url, sep='\s{2,}', engine='python')
```

Comment: I'm receiving this error. 
ParserError: Expected 8 fields in line 6, saw 9. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

Comment: I think that is because there is an "Apt Number" showing as an additional column

Comment: Please post the CSV file here if you want more help